# proceed to checkout button not working in magento 1.8.1.?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I have an problem with proceed to checkout button in magento 1.8.1 when i add some product in cart and after adding product in cart then i click on proceed to checkout button its not working. I have checked console error but still no any error show.

I have clear cache of system, browser and the magento system but still not working.

```html
<button type="button" title="Proceed to Checkout" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout no-checkout" disabled="disabled" onclick="window.location='http://samadhanmart.com/mart/index.php/checkout/onepage/';"><span><span>Proceed to Checkout</span></span></button>
```

please help me.

Answer (score -1):

Please remove `disabled="disabled"`  from  your html and  than check